# Manually set the current item in a form

Tags: google-app-maker

What is the code to manually switch a form to a specific record? I was trying to use relations but I can't make a relation to a calculated table, which is where this is coming from, so I have to hardcode which data is populated.

I'm looking for something like

```
onLoad()
(read the ID from page properties, which I use for globals)
widget.item.select(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to use:

```
widget.datasource.selectKey(id);
```

This works on the assumption that your record is currently loaded in your client however. If your record is not loaded then this will not work.